# Ruby -> get all files in directories

Tags: ruby

I want to get a list of all files in a directory that contain multiple sub-directories (and possible more sub-directories within them)

How can I do this using Ruby on my Mac OS X?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
Dir["**/*"].select{|x| !File.directory?(x)}
```